# 2D Game colision response

Tags: vector, physics, trigonometry, game-physics

So I am writing a game, but I have come to the part where i need to do some collision response, and I have been stumped. I have an algorithm that finds the objects collision angle, and collision depth meaning how much the two objects over lap. I understand what i want to do and that is to find a perpendicular vector to the collision angle and push back the object that is colliding by it's collision depth, but I just can't seem to write it correctly. 
   Here is the code I'm working with for the time being.

```
var collision:Object = collisions[i];

    var angle:Number = collision.angle;

    var overlap:Number = collision.overlapping.length;

    trace(overlap);
    trace(angle);
    var moveX = Math.cos(angle) * overlap; 
    var moveY = Math.sin(angle) * overlap;

    obj2.x -= moveX;
    obj2.y += moveY;
```

basically I just want the object that is colliding with the wall to stop when it hits it.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We really can't help you with this problem until you post the code you already have (at least the parts dealing with collisions)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on elastic collision with flash as3 once.I tried to fix overlap a lot of.But i could'nt solved it completely.They did not overlapping normally but if you forced enought, they overlapping.

if you want look at my work, i uploaded my codes.You can download and look at my code.

And if you solve this problem completely, please tell me solution.

swf(with friction, it's more problem) : http://nafiz.in/collision/carpisma.swf

swf(without friction, it's little problem than first.) : http://nafiz.in/collision/carpisma_surtunmesiz.swf

q : add a ball at mouse location.
w, a,s,d : controll #1 ball.

Click with mouse without relase and move mouse and relase. You selected balls.
When you press space, selected balls will go mouse location.

Cods : http://nafiz.in/collision/collision.rar

i hope you solve.

Comment: It seems that the speed of the ball being hit is not being increased the more overlap there is. I think that would solve the problem a bit.

Comment: Might not work, but move the ball being hit until it no longer collides. See how much it has to move, and use that to determine the velocity for the ball. I think this will solve it 100%.

Answer (score -1):

So after a few hours of tweaking the code, I came up with the solution that works well. here is my new code:

```
public function Colisions(obj1,obj2) {
        var collisions:Array=MyCollision.checkCollisions();
        for (var i = 0; i  < collisions.length; i++) {
            var collision:Object=collisions[i];
            var angle:Number=collision.angle;
            var overlap:Number=collision.overlapping.length;
            // finds the amount in x and y coordinates to move the ball back, and it devides overlap by 20 so that the ball does not jump as much. 
            var moveX=Math.cos(angle)*(overlap/20);
            var moveY=Math.sin(angle)*(overlap/20);
            // sets the ball to it's original location before the colision.
            obj2.x=obj2.x-moveX;
            obj2.y=obj2.y-moveY;


        }
    }
```

just as a side note I am using CDK which stands for the collision detection toolkit as the algorithm that finds the collisions and the info associated with the collisions.

Comment: -1 for a) not showing the logic behind the code, b) not handling the speeds during the collision and c) not considering multiple collisions on the same body.

Comment: @ja72 what do you mean not showing the logic behind the code? there is no need to handle the speed, because it's calculated on change between frames, and my object does not have acceleration... it has a fixed velocity. and multiple collisions of the same objects was not part of the requirement, but it does work if you wanted to do that with the CDK library.